# Computer won't turn on, but Power Supply light is on

Tags: power-supply, hp-pavilion

My PC won't turn on, but the power-supply light is on at the back of the computer (near the plug outlet).

I *used to* know my way around the inside of a computer, so I attempted to manually power-on the computer by touching the proper jumpers together on the motherboard.  That didn't do anything.

I'm likely just going to order a replacement power-supply at this point, but does that sound like the culprit, given that the power-supply green light turns on when plugged-in?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. You don't really have enough info to make a decent decision. A power supply tester is under $10, might be a good investment, but if your willing to blindly throw parts at it, then a PS would be a good guess, the alternative is likely the mainboard.

Comment: I'm aware of how this site works. I searched the site first, and didn't see any similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly caused by the low grade PSU's. I would recommend you to replace the PSU with the newer one (Note:if it 550W or 750W PSU i would likes to replace with that same Watt PSU) And while asking questions like this mention your PC model,details. That will be useful for troubleshooting. If you need more help comment it below. If you found this as answer mark it as answer.

Comment: It's an HP Pavilion a6750t PC.  I already had "hp-pavilion" listed in the tags.

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with the NEW PSU?.

Comment: New PS fixed the issue